# How do I map a .Net DateTime to a DB2 Date using fluent nHibernate?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, db2, data-mapping

I have the following table in my iSeries DB2 schema:

```
CREATE TABLE LATHAM1.SGINES1.LICVP010
  (ID FOR COLUMN ID10 BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   CompanyCode FOR COLUMN CONO10 CHARACTER (2) CCSID 37 NOT NULL,
   CreateDate FOR COLUMN CDAT10 DATE not null);
```

and the following mapping for the table:

```
public class OrderReferenceID
{
    public virtual long ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}

public class OrderReferenceIDMap : ClassMap<OrderReferenceID>
{
    public OrderReferenceIDMap()
    {
        Table("LICVP010");
        Id(x => x.ID, "ID10")
            .GeneratedBy.Native()
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.CompanyName, "CONO10")
            .Length(2)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.CreationDate, "CDAT10");
    }
}
```

and the following code:

```
ISessionFactory sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();

using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    OrderReferenceID newID = new OrderReferenceID { CompanyName = "LI", CreationDate = DateTime.Now.Date };

    session.Save(newID);
    session.Flush();
    session.Close();
}
```

When I execute this, I get an error:

```
A conversion error occurred.
```

This appears to be happening because of the conversion from CLR DateTime to DB2 Date object.

How can I properly map this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that modifying this line

```
Map(x => x.CreationDate, "CDAT10");
```

to this

```
Map(x => x.CreationDate, "CDAT10")
    .CustomType("Date");
```

fixed the problem.